# Spring Boot Admin error from Client side in port

Tags: java, port, client-side, spring-boot-admin

everyone!

I have a problem with Spring Boot Admin in Client side:

```
01-04-2021 23:02:37 [registrationTask1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties.getBasePath()Ljava/lang/String;
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.ServletApplicationFactory.getManagementContextPath(ServletApplicationFactory.java:86)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.ServletApplicationFactory.getManagementBaseUrl(ServletApplicationFactory.java:77)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.DefaultApplicationFactory.getHealthUrl(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:154)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.DefaultApplicationFactory.createApplication(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:80)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.DefaultApplicationRegistrator.register(DefaultApplicationRegistrator.java:56)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

my pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

my application.yaml:

```yaml
spring.boot.admin:
  client:
    url: http://localhost:8080
    username: admin
    password: admin
    instance:
      metadata:
        user:
          name: ${spring.security.user.name}
          password: ${spring.security.user.password}
---
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: httptrace,loggers,health,info,metrics
```

Admin-side works perfect. Client-side, when I write "url: http://localhost:8080" has error.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds similar to https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/1719

The `getBasePath()` method (being used by Spring Boot Admin Client 2.4) has been introduced with Spring Boot 2.4, are you sure that Spring Boot 2.4 is used at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

May be your dependency versions of the admin server and admin client are different. And spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency may not be required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).